Code intercepted - BLASE+LBSA=BASES. Can there be two solutions?
This question is from the book 'Mathematical Circles', and it goes like this:

The secret service of The Federation intercepted a coded message from
the Dominion which read: BLASE + LBSA = BASES. It is known that equal
digits are coded with equal letters and different digits with
different letters. Two giant computers came up with two different
answers to the riddle. Is this possible or does one of them require
repair?

The answer given is:

There is only one answer: 51286 + 1582 = 52868. 
Hints:  L+L < 10  S+S
$ \geq $ 10 If this did not hold, hundreds and units digits of $BASES$ would not be
equal ($B \neq E$).

I was able to find the above solution but I am not able to see how there cannot be two answers. I know why $L+ L <10$ but I have trouble understanding why $S+S \geq 10$. As per my understanding, If:
$E + A < 10$  Then $S + S > 10$. But why are we sure that this statement will hold if $E +A > 10$? I have also not arrived at any scenario where the contradiction $B=E$ arose.

This is more a puzzle than a math question , although we can also apply logic instead of pure brute force. But I doubt we can solve this puzzle with logic alone and without any trial and error.

$E+A\ge 10$ is not possible.
Looking at the units' digits, if $E+A\ge 10$ then $E+A=10+S$ with a carry to the tens' digits.  Then

either $S+S+1=E$ in the tens digits with no carry to the hundreds' digits

in which case in the hundreds' digits, you need either $A+B =S$ (i.e. the impossible $B=E-10$) or $A+B=10+S$ (i.e. the prohibited $B=E$);


or $S+S+1=10+E$ in the tens' digits (with a carry), which would make $A+S=19$ (impossible with two single digits).


So $E+A< 10$, and thus you need $S+S \ge 10$ to avoid $B=E$ from the units' and hundreds' digits.

Thanks a lot! This helps very much. Just one thing- Shouldn't it be S+S> 10 as otherwise E=0 and thus A=S? Also how do we proceed further with these two statements?

@Pumpkin_Star: I put $S+S \ge 10$ just to indicate there must be a carry.  You can then go on to reject more specific values, as you do.  But your original question said things like "S+S> or = 10".
